# Oracle Apex inconsistent asterisk side

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

We found out that on different fields on the page the asterisk of a required field is sometimes left to the text and sometimes right to the text.

I'm talking only about the **`Appearance-->template`-->`Required`** and **not** about `Required-above`/`Required-above-Asterick left`

[image]
[image]

I couldn't find anything that makes the difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is Difference I attached image, Required TextField has Label + * on left but in Required Above has Label with * Above Textfield
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32w3V.png)

Comment: Please use markdown to clarify your response (see the +)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading APEX from 18.2 to 20.2.

After investigation, I found out that in my case, the position of the asterisk depends on the *Template Options* of the region where the item is located.
By default, the asterisk is on the left side of the label, but if you change the *Item Width* to *Stretch Form Fields* the asterisk will switch to the right side of the label.
Of course, after that, you need to adjust the item width by using the item's *Layout* options like *Column*, *Column Span*, and *Label Column Span*.